# Unity3D - cannot read new content of other class from new scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, runtime-error, unityscript

I have this problem in Unity. Basically, I have this following class Constant.cs, contains the following:

`public static int base_x = 480;`

It is readable from all my existing scene. But the problem occurs when I create new Scene, and attach a script into it. Once I try to read Constant.base_x, it throws this following error:

`NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Constant..cctor ()`
Rethrow as `TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Constant`

There is no issue if I attach the very same script to all my existing scene. Only the new scene throw this error.

What is happening? I tried to clean and rebuild the whole project (using MonoDevelop), but error still occurs...

Comment: Welcome to StockOver flow. Please add the portion of Constant.cs Script and the script that is calling the Static that is member variable.

Comment: It seems like you have a static constructor in the `Constant` class, and it's throwing an exception.

Comment: thanks all, I found the problem. It is actually I haven't instantiated another object, not this Constant class. Not sure why Unity pointed the error into this class. :)